# KeyListener with JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, null, keylistener, jformattedtextfield

Can someone explain to me why the `getValue()` function returns `null` always? If I use `getText()` instead of `getValue()` then everything is perfect, but what I want is the value and not the text. I can convert it to an integer, but I don't think that this is the best way.

```
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame("test jftf"); 
        jf.setSize(100, 100);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        jf.setVisible(true); 
        JFormattedTextField jftf = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()); 
        jftf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println(jftf.getValue()); 
            }

        });
        jf.add(jftf); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are relying on the `getValue()` method, you need to make sure that current edits have been committed. You can do this by calling the the method `commitEdit()` otherwise you may not get the values you are expecting:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    //Forces the current value to be taken from the AbstractFormatter 
    //and set as the current value:
    try {
        jftf.commitEdit();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        //Handle possible parsing error...
    }
    System.out.println(jftf.getValue()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but first, I need to surround the statment with try and catch, second, I don't understand why do I need this commitEdit() function? When I use an ActionListener, I don't have this problem.

Comment: Updated to handle exception.  I don't understand why it works without the commit in the `ActionListener` to be honest, I can only assume there are differences in the implementation!

Comment: Thank you very much anyway. At least, now, the code works :)

Comment: Looking at the code, I suspect the `ActionEvent` is fired at a higher level than the `KeyPress` event, at which point the value has been committed internally within the component.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to show how this works the names of the values are not accurate.
Think of it like this.
**JFormattedTextField** has a field called **lastValidInt** that holds an integer.
Every time the text in the field is formatted then the program will check if the text in the field is a number. If it is then lastValidInt will be set to that string.

The `getValue()` method will check if **lastValidInt** has been initialized and if it has then it returns the value of **lastValidInt**. If it hasn't then it returns **null**.

Examples:
These assume that you are restarting the application each time.
Input is what you will write in the field.
Output is what the console will print after entering something.

```
1:
Input: a
Ouput: null
//a is not a number therefore the output is null

2:
Input:  1
Output: 1
//1 is a number therefore the output is 1

3:
Input1: a
Ouput: null
Input2: as
Ouput: null
Input3: asd
Ouput: null
Input4: asdf
Ouput: null
//a is not a number therefore the output is null

4:
Input1: 1
Ouput: 1
Input2: 1f
Ouput: 1
//The first thing the was read here was 1 therefore lastValidInt was set to 1 then the next input is 1f which is not a number therefore lastValidInt remained 1

5:
Input1: f
Ouput: null
Input2: f1
Ouput: null
//f is not a number therefore output is null, f1 is not a number either since it has a character that is not a digit and therefore lastValidInt has not been initialized

6:
Input1: f
Ouput: null
Input2: 
Output: null
Input3: 1
Output: 1
Input4: 1f
Output: 1
//f is not a number therefore output is null, "" is also not a number therefore output is null again then the only thing that exists in the field is 1 which is a number therefore output is 1, finally by adding a f the field is no longer a number so output is same as before.

7:
Input1: f
Ouput: null
Input2: 1f (moved back to the begining without erasing f)
Output: null
//f is not a number therefore output is null, 1f is not a number either since it has a character that is not a digit and therefore lastValidInt has not been initialized
```

Comment: Can you precise that a little bit? If I type the "4" key for example, why does the getValue() return null? It is a number, so it shouldn't return null.

Comment: @ardayigit There you go, made some examples for you

Comment: @ardayigit well i guess you also need to commit the changes. Worked for me though.

Comment: With the commit, your examples work fine, but I still don't understand why do I need to commit the changes. When I use it with an ActionListener, I don't need to use the commitEdit() function.

Comment: @ardayigit Could be a different version. It depends on the actionlistener

Comment: Here is an example where I don't need to commit. 
    jftf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(jftf.getValue());
            }
            
        });

Comment: @ardayigit Oh, i was using an actionListener. Didn't realize you had a keyListener. Though i don't get why they would have a different effect.